# Mask SSN input except last 4 digits and format input on keyup using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an input for social security number and want to add dashes to the input while masking the last 4 digits.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $(".ssnclass").keyup(function () {
        $('.ssnclass').val(function (index, value) {            
            return value.replace(/\d(?=.*\d{4})/g, "*");
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you looked at using a plugin like  jQuery-Mask-Plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: I did Patrick, but it will mask the first digits and never let the user sees what he's typing. The requirement was to let the user see his input then mask everything except the last 4 digits. The code I have is working except I need the formatting. Thank you-